# Let $M_{0}:=\{f \in C[0,1] \mid f(0)=0 \}$. Show that $M_0$ is not a finitely generated ideal of $C[0,1]$.

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

We let $M_0=(f_1,f_2, \ldots ,f_n)$. Now if we consider the function $g(x)=\cos(x) \not \in M_0$, we observe that since $M_0$ is a maximal ideal of $C[0,1]$, $C[0,1]=(f_1,f_2, \ldots,f_n,g(x))$. I wanted to show that this is not possible, but I am stuck.

I saw the proof using the function $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n (|f_i(x)|)^{\frac{1}{2}}$, so I don't want to see that proof again. Any hints on how to proceed or any other way without actually finding a function would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why did you use $g(x)=\cos x$ instead of simply $g(x)=1$? It makes no difference as one of the $f_i$ might be $\cos x -1$, but ...

Comment: The idea is that among the finitely many generators, there is only a maximal "steepness" with which they approach $0$ as $x\to 0$. Therefore any function in $M_0$ that is much steeper requires a coefficient that grows beyond all bounds as $x\to 0$, which is not possible. - Your attempt amounts to showing that $C[0,1]$ is not finitely generated - which I would but do by showing that $M_0$ is not.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen , $g(x)=1$ generates $C[0,1]$. Now that you mention it, my approach might not then lead to a contradiction. Or is there a way to modify $g(x)$ so that we reach a contradiction?

Comment: I think modify $g(x)$ can never leads to a proof. $g(x)-g(0)$ is in $M_0$, so $f(x)\equiv g(0)$ belongs to $M_0+(g(x))$. If $g(0)\not=0$, $f(x)$ generates $C[0,1]$, no conclusion is drawn. Otherwise $g(0)=0$ and $g(x)\in M_0$, still no conclusion.